# How can I use one query to resolve many Rest round trips in graphQL?

Tags: rest, graphql, apollo-server

I'm trying to resolve a REST query using GraphQL and Apollo.

My rest data looks like this

Pass a fund id to a splits resolver which returns a -> [Splits array] -> each split has a donation_id -> I want to use that ID to get the {donation} object from a separate rest endpoint

Here is my schema

```
export const schema = [`

schema {
  query: RootQuery
}

type RootQuery {
  Splits(id: Int!): [Splits]
}

type Splits {
    amount_in_cents:Int
    donation_id:Int
    fund_id:Int
    id:Int
    memo:String
    donation(donation_id: Int): Donation
}

type Donation {
  amount_in_cents: Int
  bank_name: String
}
`];
```

And here is my resolver file

```
import rp from 'request-promise';

const DTBaseURL = 'https://restendpointdomainhere.com/';
const getFromDT = (getQuery) => {
  const data = rp( DTBaseURL + getQuery, {
    'auth': {
      "user": Meteor.settings.endpoint.user,
      "pass": Meteor.settings.endpoint.pass,
    }
  } )
    .then( ( res ) => JSON.parse( res ) )
    .then((res) =>{
      return res;
    });
  return data;
};



export default resolveFunctions = {
  RootQuery: {
    Splits( root, args, context ){
      let newValue = [];
      const getQuery = 'funds/' + args.id + '/splits.json';

      const data = getFromDT(getQuery)
        .then( ( res ) => {
          res.forEach( function ( donationSplit ) {
            newValue.push( donationSplit.split );
          } );
          return newValue;
        } );

      return data;
    },
    donation( root, args, context ){
      console.log( args );
      const getQuery = 'donations/' + args.donation_id + '.json';

      const data = getFromDT(getQuery)
        .then((res) => {
          return res.donation;
        });
      return data;
    }
  }
};
```

Any query I do @ /graphql gets me this error message.

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Resolve function missing for \"Splits.donation\""
    }
  ]
}
```

Any help here is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using graphql-tools to create your schema. This error message tells you that your schema cannot be built successfully because the `donation` field on `Splits` needs a resolve function. You defined the resolve function, but you put it inside `RootQuery` instead of `Splits` where it belongs:

```
export default resolveFunctions = {
  RootQuery: {
    Splits( root, args, context ){
      let newValue = [];
      const getQuery = 'funds/' + args.id + '/splits.json';

      const data = getFromDT(getQuery)
        .then( ( res ) => {
          res.forEach( function ( donationSplit ) {
            newValue.push( donationSplit.split );
          } );
          return newValue;
        } );

      return data;
    },
  },
  Splits: { // <<---- you forgot this ------
    donation( root, args, context ){
      console.log( args );
      const getQuery = 'donations/' + args.donation_id + '.json';

      const data = getFromDT(getQuery)
        .then((res) => {
          return res.donation;
        });
      return data;
    }
  },
};
```

Comment: Thanks. Now how do I allow the donation_id to pass from the query response into this resolver? Here is what I have in GraphiQL

    {
      Splits(id: 71455){
        amount_in_cents
        donation_id
        donation(donation_id: donation_id){
          amount_in_cents
        }
      }
    }

Comment: the `donation` resolver will get the object that you return from the `Splits` resolver as the first argument, and all the GraphQL arguments (including donation_id) as the second argument.

Comment: So from your description it seems like you don't even need the donation_id argument in your field, because each split has exactly one donation, so the donation_id can be part of the split object which the donation resolver gets as the first argument.